# Cannot Create AWS Aurora Serverless Database with Default Options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to create a new Aurora Serverless Database by with the following options
"Easy Create"
"MySQL"
"Serverless"
Giving a username and password

When I click "Create Database" I get this error message:
"Your request to create DB instance database-1 didn't work.
Aurora Serverless currently doesn't support IAM Authentication."

I am signed in as a Root User and do not see any other options in the "Easy Create" menu to set controls for authentication, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trying to enable [IAM Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html) when you create the cluster, but this features not supported yet for Aurora Serverless.

It seems like this is a bug as you cannot change the option, so worth raising with AWS.

To get around this whenever you use the Easy Create option at the bottom of the screen you can get a list of all the settings. You will need to create your Aurora Serverless cluster manually but you can use the settings as a point of reference for creating

Comment: Thanks! It's a little weird that I had to come here to figure out that IAM Authentication wasn't supported for Aurora Serverless... seems like an AWS failure to communicate imho